# Can Free Roaming Dog be antagonizing the crated dog thus causing her to pee in it?

Tags: dogs, behavior

We have a two year old BC rescue and adopted an Aussie rescue several months back and who will be one year old in a month.  The Aussie was a bit tough to train as she instinctively needed to mark.  The BC has not been the happiest in having a new sibling but they are learning to navigate it and for the most part living harmoniously.  However, to keep both safe and to avoid any possible dog altercations while we are out, the Aussie is crated and the BC is able to roam freely.  The Aussie has always done great in the crate but the last three weeks on a couple of occasions where she was in the crate for no more than three hours she has peed in the crate.  Honestly, I do not believe it is any type of medical issue because in between those days she was crated and for longer periods due to work schedule and nothing.  I feel that it is some type of antagonizing that the BC might doing and thus the Aussie is peeing to mark.  I would love to hear others thoughts on this theory.  I am considering obtaining a camera to be able to watch what kind of interacting is happening to prompt this but in the meantime looking to hear if anyone has ever experienced this and how they handled it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, crating only one dog always leads to more stress for the crated dog.

Dogs can (to a certain extend) emphasize with other dogs and humans and put themselves in their shoes. They also have a sense of fairness and equity. If you let 2 dogs perform the same trick but reward one dog much better than the other one, the second dog will eventually refuse to perform.

In the case of crating only one dog, it can lead to several problems:

- The crated dog may want to play or otherwise interact with the roaming dog and is hindered by the crate.
- The crated dog wants to roam free but cannot. At the same time she can see another dog roaming free and understands that the other dog is free. This is very frustrating.
- The other dog may display dominant behavior or even start a fight. Since the crated dog is hindered in her movements, she may resort to marking or more intense shows of aggression.
- The other possibility is that she's so intimidated by the roaming dog that she pees as a gesture of submission. This kind of behavior is common in puppies.

Whatever the reason may be, the crate gets associated with negative feelings and becomes a punishment. Since the dog isn't really punished for any bad behavior, she can never avoid being crated (punished), which is incredibly frustrating, especially for an intelligent dog like an aussie.

There's another possible problem lurking here. If the Aussie is the dominant* dog but gets crated while the other one roams free, she can perceive that as insubordinate behavior. Confining a dog to a corner is natural dominant dog behavior, but with the crate you create this behavior artificially and put her in the submissive role. She might become extra dominant to assert her position.

*Dominant doesn't neseccarily mean aggressive. Dogs can be dominant and very gentle at the same time, but usually they expect a certain amount of respect and submissive behavior from the other dogs in their pack. If other dogs are disrespectful (ignore the hierarchy) they can ramp up the shows of dominance to assert their rank.

If it's possible in any way, I would either crate both dogs or let both roam free. By treating them the same, you avoid frustration and feelings of unfairness and you avoid interfering with their hierarchy. If you cannot do that and have to crate one dog, at least do it in a way she cannot see the free roaming dog.

Comment: Hi Elmy, Thank you for your reply. Since adopting my Aussie my BC has become a bit territorial and for this reason there are arguments for the most part it is noise but once in awhile and can become more so I am fearful of putting her in a vulnerable situation even though she is the larger dog I feel she is the submissive with the two.

Comment: I had hit my send button too quickly and would like to add:  Dare I take the chance and not crate her?  Also, my BC had very little exposure to a crate as she only needed it for a brief period while training so putting her in one does not seem fair to her.  I must admit I am torn.  Honestly, I am a mom of four and I am finding a fur mom of two to be much harder, lol.  I had a behavioral trainer come in and honestly she was expensive and no help.  Any additional information you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Being in the crate while the other one can roam is just as unfair to the Aussie. And both BC and Aussie are among the most extreme high maintenance breeds of dogs in the entire world, so no wonder it's hard on you. That's most likely why they ended up in a shelter. My advice for you: Look through [other questions about aggression between dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-pet-families+dogs+aggression) and watch some YouTube videos that help you recognize signs of aggression. Then observe your dogs. Will they really hurt each other or is it just posing and barking?

Comment: Caring for them both is not hard in fact I enjoy & love my girls! It's the guarding/protectiveness the BC is displaying that makes me worry and what is hard on me. A trait she never displayed until we took in our Aussie.  I have watched YouTube & hired a behavior trainer who didn't feel there was an issue, I do not agree. I watch my BC's demeanor & can tell when she is not happy and most times I am able to diffuse it. I must mention, my Aussie is crated no more than two hours/4 times a week, while I go to work/my husband returns.  The rest of the time they are both free to roam/play.

Comment: It is only occasionally where she has had to be in it longer but oddly enough those times have not had an issue.  Also one other thing to mention is she is still very mischievous and I feel the crate protects her from getting into something that may possibly harm her and hoping with a little more time this will work itself out as she tends to take a little longer to learn things.  However I do agree the being crated while the other is not is not a good message and will need to do something different.

Comment: Thank you for your help and thoughts it has certainly made me realize and see this in a different view.